# How can I avoid being logged in again when clicking back button of browser in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

How can I avoid being logged in again when clicking back button of browser in codeigniter? I destroy de session when logout but when i clic back in the browser it still enters the admin page, when clicking the back button of browser It should stay in the redirected page and not get back to admin page. this is my code in the model and controller:

```
   auth_model:
    class Auth_model extends CI_Model {


        public function login($name, $password){
           $password = sha1($password);

            $this->db->where('username',$name);
            $this->db->where('password',$password);
            $query = $this->db->get('auth');
            if($query->num_rows()==1){
                foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                    $data = array(
                                'username'=> $row->username,
                                'logged_in'=>TRUE
                            );
                }
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                return TRUE;
            }
            else{
                return FALSE;
          }    
        }

        public function isLoggedIn(){
                header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
                header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
                $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

                if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in!==TRUE)
                {
                    redirect('/');
                    exit;
                }
        }
   auth controller:
        public function logout(){
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                redirect('/' ,'refresh');
                exit;
            } 

user controller
<?php 
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->template->set_layout('adminLayout.php');
        $this->load->model("User_model");
        $this->load->Model('Auth_model'); 
    }


    function index()
    {
        $this->Auth_model->isLoggedIn();
        $this->template->title('Admin ::');
        $this->template->build('admin/index');
    }

        function user()
    {
         $this->Auth_model->isLoggedIn();
        $this->template->title('user');
        $this->template->build('admin/user');
    }


?>
```

Comment: you need to provide more code

Comment: You can also use session unset before destroying the session, one more thing, if you use caching then It might possible that your browser may show admin page. else you can use to call login function instead of redirecting. like: $this->login(); in the controller

Comment: I tried what you said  but it still keeps the same problem

Comment: Where do you call admin template ? Do check if logged in ? Plus your isLoggedIn() function should just return TRUE or FALSE, in case you want to get this info without doing a redirection. Redirection must happen in your controller.

Comment: I added the code of user controller where i call the admin layout

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the header page-

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE, must-revalidate">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT=0>`

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

The above worked fine for me for the same issue.

Comment: I'm using a codeigniter template library for admin layout and homepage layout, for header page you mean to put the <metas inside the tags <head></head> of the admin layout? and header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); is php code inside that <head> too?

Comment: yeah, the php code also on the same page and inside the <head> tag.